# How to get taxonomy by URL alias?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have a *grade* vocabulary with a *6. Class* taxonomy term. The taxonomy page have an URL like 
www.example.com/foo/6-class/bar and I can't find the taxonomy with the following code.

```
$grade = arg(2);
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($grade)
```

It works when I use a string (e.g. *6. Class*), but not with `arg(2)`. How can I get the correct taxonomy with this URL alias? Problem might be, that it is a exposed filter and no contextual filter. But I can not change this fact.

Neither I can get the source path with the following code.

```
drupal_lookup_path('source', $_GET['q']);
drupal_lookup_path('alias', current_path());
```

Comment: when you try to get arg(2) , what getting returned for you? ( term id or something like 6-class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a pretty old question but seems unanswered yet.
This Drupal 7 snippet will help you to load a taxonomy term but you need to know the name of the vocabulary it belongs to, lets say it is 'position'.
Ex. www.example.com/foo/6-class/bar

```
$term_path=drupal_get_normal_path('position/'.arg(1));
$tid = basename($term_url);
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
```

If you **know** your url is an alias to your taxonomy term, just use

```
$term_path=drupal_get_normal_path(current_path());
$tid = basename($term_url);
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
```

The drupal_lookup_path with source and uri approach did not work for you because probably that path is not an alias, or at least not for your taxonomy.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I was working in Drupal 8 and for whatever reason I couldn't get any of the above solutions to work for me. Below is what I ended up using to get the url with the term id. There must better ways of doing this and I'm sure that not all of these options are required, but I hope this helps someone.

```
$term_url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', ['taxonomy_term' => $term->tid->value], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

`arg(2)` will return the term id of the taxonomy term not the name because the path will be `taxonomy/term/[tid]`.

You have added an alias for the term pages which the `arg()` function doesn't read as it reads the original path not the aliased path.

The function that you are using with take the taxonomy name as the argument. But what you are passing is the term id. So if you use `taxonomy_term_load(arg(2))` then you will get details about the term in the returned term object.

Check out the documentation here: 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Content of `arg(2)` is exactly this what I see in url `6-class`. And `taxonomy_term_load` has same result as `taxonomy_get_term_by_name` -> false.

Comment: So www.example.com/foo/6-class/bar is a custom built path or a path alias of taxonomy terms?

Comment: It is made by an exposed filter.

Comment: Ok. But still then `arg(2)` will give you `bar`.
Anyways if that is the case then you have to check the value of `arg(1)` convert it to actual term name.
if the pattern of the term names are similar then you can try out this http://pastebin.com/iaMi9v6Z

Comment: Yeah, thanks - I know this approach. But there are several more issues. Like in we got letters like `ö` that are in computer language `oe`. So I would have to ` `strreplace` term by term and actually I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way to get taxonomy term from url is

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
```