# Get taxonomy term ID from standard URL and then pass it to a View as a contextual filter

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

is a simple question, I whant get the term ID (tid) from standard drupal taxonomy url taxonomy/term/167 ou 167 is my tid and use as argument on views.

I found this code to get the tid:

```
$term_path=drupal_get_normal_path('position/'.arg(1));
$tid = basename($term_url);
$$here_is_my_tid = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
```

[How to get taxonomy by URL alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161578/how-to-get-taxonomy-by-url-alias)

I try also :

```
$here_is_my_tid = drupal_lookup_path('source', 'taxonomy/term/'.$tid);


$here_is_my_tid = drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/' . $tid);
```

But I try many combination without success.

Here is my views with the tid from url I try to pass "$here_is_my_tid"

```
$view1 = views_embed_view('mavue','page',$here_is_my_tid);

 if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
            $tid = (int)arg(2);
            $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

      }
    $view1 = views_embed_view('mavue','page',$term);
```

By advance thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the TID from the standard URL and then pass it to the views as a contextual filter, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get taxonomy by URL alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161578/how-to-get-taxonomy-by-url-alias)

Comment: @usmanjutt84 Yes I  want to get the TID from the standard URL and then pass it to the views as a contextual filter

Comment: link above does not help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not have to write any code to achieve that.**

Just go to the views edit page, add a contextual filter named as **Has taxonomy term ID** and select **Provide default value**, see screenshot for more options

[image]

**However, you can also do it pragmatically**

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
   $term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
   if ($term && $term->vocabulary_machine_name == 'VOCABULARY_NAME') {
     if ($view->name=='VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME') {
       $view->query->where['0']['conditions']['0']['value']= $term->tid;
     }
   }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can also take help from this tutorial https://youtu.be/XI0iNYpaJ9o?t=114 for passing TID using Drupal Interface.

Comment: Hi, I know for "has taxonomy term ID from views UI" but I use an ajax callback so I need to do programatically. I try you're programatically solution who look well I Haven't think about use a views_query_alter, many thanks

Comment: I sent you a message if you can check thanks